# How to approach nested generation strategy when testing?

Tags: java, testing, junit, jemos-podam

I am writing a test with JUnit 5 and I have a class named TicketRequest. In this class there are various String variables, List < String > variables. For these Podam has no problem populating.

The issue I am facing is in regards with other user created reference variables such as:

1. List < Account > accounts;
2. List < Document > documents;
   .. etc.

Some of these classes have themselves references to other classes. This might continue once or twice again.

I cannot modify the aforementioned classes (adding PODAM annotations above variables), all logic must be implemented in the test class. How can I approach this situation and best configure PODAM strategy to generate and populate the necessary variables ?

Comment: Not my decision. It's a framework I have to use.